# QuestDB - Declaring variables or performing math in SAMPLE BY function

Tags: sql, grafana, questdb

**Background:**

I am using *Telegraf*, *QuestDB*, and *Grafana* to visualize high-frequency time-series data. In order to reduce the time Grafana takes to query long time ranges of data, I need leverage QuestDB's `SAMPLE BY` function.

**Goal:**

I need to make my QuestDB query dynamic based on a simple math equation leveraging Grafana's system variable *$__interval_ms* and an arbitrary numeric.

**Expected:**

In query below, I am attempting to leverage Grafana's system variables to make my query dynamic. I am expecting QuestDB to understand and perform the mathematical operation necessary to complete the `SAMPLE BY` function.

```
SELECT ts time, last(x), last(y), last(z)
FROM accelerometer
WHERE $__timeFilter(ts)
SAMPLE BY ($__interval_ms/1000)T
```

After Grafana processes this query, it is passed to QuestDB as...

```
SELECT ts time, last(x), last(y), last(z)
FROM accelerometer
WHERE ts BETWEEN '2021-10-12T00:00:00.000Z' AND '2021-10-12T01:00:00.000Z'
SAMPLE BY (30000/1000)T
```

*NOTE: if I replace `SAMPLE BY (300000/1000)T` with `SAMPLE BY 30T`, the query performs as expected.*

**Result:**

QuestDB does not recognize that I wish to perform a mathematical operation and fails.

**Steps I've Taken:**

I have tried to do the following as workarounds:

1. declare a variable via `DECLARE @sampler` -- failed
2. perform a `WITH` statement before the query via `WITH sampler as (SELECT concat($__interval_ms / 1000, 'T')` and then reference `sampler` at the end via `SAMPLE BY sampler` -- failed
3. perform the math in a Grafana variable (via their standard dashboard variable GUI) -- failed
4. embedding a `SELECT` statement in the `SAMPLE BY` function -- failed

So far I've had absolutely no luck.

How can I either store a variable in QuestDB (similar to `DECLARE` in Postgres) or perform mathematical operations in the `SAMPLE by` function? Or is there another way to tackle this problem that I am not thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

QuestDB as of 6.0.9 cannot parse non-constant `SAMPLE BY` period, is a way it can do `SAMPLE BY 100s` but cannot do arithmetic expression like `SAMPLE BY 1000/10s`.